# jQuery Tabs with Animations

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery tab section - and I want to animate the panels within it. Below is the code.
I basically want to make the "vertical-tabstrip-visible-content" a sliding panel - such that as each link is clicked, it will close the existing panels and slide the correct, corrosponding one into view.

Any ideas how this could be achieved using jQuery?
(I'm already using jQuery UI tabs for the tabbing effect).

```
   <div id="tabstrip" class="vertical-tabstrip" >
    <ul class="vertical-tabstrip-tabs">
        <li><a href="#vid-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vid-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vid-3">Tab 3</a></li>                                         
    </ul>
    <div class="vertical-tabstrip-visible-content-container" id="vid-1"><div class="vertical-tabstrip-visible-content">Content 1</div></div>
    <div class="vertical-tabstrip-visible-content-container" id="vid-2"><div class="vertical-tabstrip-visible-content">Content 2</div></div>
    <div class="vertical-tabstrip-visible-content-container" id="vid-3"><div class="vertical-tabstrip-visible-content">Content 3</div></div>                    
</div>

/**********************************************************
 jQUERY UI TABSTRIP
***********************************************************/

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
     display: none;
}

.ui-tabs a {

}
.ui-tabs-selected a {
    border-style: none;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-width: 0;
    background: url('../../images/demo-config-on.gif') no-repeat right 50% #f8a230;
    padding-right:18px;     color:#fff;     margin-right:-10px;     margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/**********************************************************
 HORIZONTAL TABSTRIP
***********************************************************/

.vertical-tabstrip {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.vertical-tabstrip-tabs {
    float: left;
    width: 260px;   
    margin: 0px;
    background: #000;
}

.vertical-tabstrip-tabs li {
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 3px 0;
}
.vertical-tabstrip-tabs li a:link,
.vertical-tabstrip-tabs li a:visited {
    display:block; padding:1px 8px 4px;
}

* html .vertical-tabstrip-tabs li a:link,
* html .vertical-tabstrip-tabs li a:visited {
     padding:1px 8px 2px;
}

.vertical-tabstrip-tabs li a:hover,
.vertical-tabstrip-tabs li a:active {
    background-color:#f8a230
}

.vertical-tabstrip-visible-content-container {
    padding: 3px 0 0 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}
.vertical-tabstrip-visible-content {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the accordion control what you are looking for? http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Look on the right hand side - those tabs. 
They link to different HTML pages - I want to load the DIVs, but I want to add .animate attributes to the div that is loading.

Comment: The thing I cannot figure out how to do is to have the inner layer have an .animate applied to it and close any others that are open. I was seeing if there was some jQuery logic that I could use to avoid a huge series of manual link assignments.

Comment: See, I have found the fx option for the tabstrip , but I am very confused about how to use it...

$('.selector').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });

What all can I pass through this? What does it mean by 'opacity: toggle'? What is it toggling? etc? I cannot find a parameter list of things that are valid.

Comment: can you rephrase what are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ah! I did it! 
$('#tabstrip').tabs({ fx: { width: 'show', duration: 'slow'} });

It slides the tab panes in and out on tabchange!

Comment: The fx parameters are the same as animate: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use the fx: feature within jquery.

```
 $('#tabstrip').tabs({ fx: { width: 'show', duration: 'slow'} });
```

Still, I am very confused about what can be passed through this function. If anyone has ideas, I would love to know!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [LocalScroll](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/) plugin?